# amqp gets prepended to celery broker url

Tags: django, celery

Specifying broker_url with `redis://redis:6379/0` is getting overwritten to `amqp://guest:**@redis%2F%2Fredis%3A6379%2F0:5672/`

logs
Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@redis%2F%2Fredis%3A6379%2F0:5672//: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.

Setup

Structure

```
config/
  settings/
    common.py
    dev.py
  celery.py
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  django: &django_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/django/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/facebook_scraper
    environment:
      DOTTED_SETTINGS_PATH: 'config.settings.dev'
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - selenium
  
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.8
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  celery_worker:
    <<: *django_container
    ports: []
    command: celery -A config.celery worker -l INFO
```

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

dotted_settings_path = os.environ.get('DOTTED_SETTINGS_PATH')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', dotted_settings_path)

app = Celery(
    'facebook_scraper',
    # backend='redis://redis:6379/0',
    # broker='redis://redis:6379/0',
)
app.conf.update(
    broker_url='redis://redis:6379/0',
)
# app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Comment: did you install `celery` with `redis` support? `pip install celery[redis]`